# Problem with Firebase Hosting creating a custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have created a custom domain for the authentication mail templates in firebase, at the same time I have created a custom index.html in the hosting section. Now when I send password recovery emails the URL is not working, it just shows my index.html. Anyone have any idea what I might be missing.

Before it worked with the default UI of firebase for password recovery and email verification

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the same custom domain, make sure that the configured URL for Authentication has the format `https://example.com/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>`; this is also assuming that the custom domain is correctly configured in Hosting.